# Discord bot not performing functions with no errors

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am extremely new to coding and trying to make a discord bot. I am following a series of youtube tutorials and seem to have hit a hitch. My goal is to create a discord bot that can join a voice channel, play an mp3 audio, then leave. However, I am currently stuck at getting the bot to leave a voice channel, and getting the bot to play an mp3 audio. I am using Python 3.7.9 and Visual studio code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio

TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '!', intents=intents)



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ITS WORKING")
    print("------------------------")


@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("ITS WORKING")


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.voice):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()

    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel, you must be in a voice channel to run this command")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    if (ctx.voice_client):
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send("I left the voice channel")
    else:
         await ctx.send("I am not in a voice channel")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def mo(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.voice):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = await channel.connect()
        source= FFmpegPCMAudio('mo.mp3')
        player = voice.play(source)

    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")


client.run(TOKEN)
```

This is my current code. I do not get any errors when I execute any commands, but the leave function does not cause the bot to leave the voice channel. And the !mo function joins the voice channel but does not play any audio. the mp3 file is in the correct location (I think) and I've added FFmpeg to path, however I could not find the same FFmpeg download they used in the youtube tutorial, so I am using a different one. Please help!!!

Answer (score 3):

I've tested your code and you are missing the `message_content` intent.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
```

Source: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#commands

Without this line the bot is unresponsive to commands. You won't see any logs because it's simply not reacting.

It's weird to me that you were able to join with the bot though... But besides this line the whole code works.

Comment: when I added that I got this error: "AttributeError: 'Intents' object has no attribute 'message_content'"

Comment: @ahmarabeh that's really strange, it should. Are you using an older version or perhaps fork of discord.py?

Comment: @CrazyChucky I'm not really sure. How do I check which version I am on?

Comment: I just looked it up and discord.py doesn't support anything older than python 3.8. I am using 3.7.9, how do I easily update my code to a new version

Comment: The way to udate python depends on the machine you are using @ahmarabeh. If you are using windows so you can download a more recent version from the python page and install it. If it's not for a compatibility reason you it'd be the best to use 3.11.   

For Linux you could use https://www.tecmint.com/install-python-in-ubuntu/ or compile it by yourself https://fostips.com/install-python-3-10-debian-11/ (do this for 3.11, not 3.10)

Comment: @ahmarabeh Although I wouldn't recommend the following, do this if you're having a ton of issues. Try `discord.Intents.all()`. This will enable all intents. Good luck!